# Why the error will cause the koa application to stop

Tags: javascript, ldap, passport.js, koa2, koa-passport

This is the code i used

**auth.js**

```
const passport = require('koa-passport')
const options = {
    server: {
          ...
    }
};
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user)
})
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user)
})
const ldapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth').Strategy
passport.use(new ldapStrategy(options, function(user, done, error) {
    done(null, user)
}))
```

**index.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa()

// trust proxy
app.proxy = true

// sessions
const convert = require('koa-convert')
const session = require('koa-generic-session')
app.keys = ['your-session-secret']
app.use(convert(session()))

// body parser
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')
app.use(bodyParser())

// authentication
require('./auth')
const passport = require('koa-passport')
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// routes
const fs = require('fs')
const route = require('koa-route')

app.use(route.get('/', function(ctx) {
    ctx.type = 'html'
    ctx.body = fs.createReadStream('views/login.html')
}))

app.use(route.post('/login', (ctx, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('ldapauth', { session: false }, (err, user, info, status) => {
        if (user === false) {
            ctx.body = { success: false }
            throw new TypeError('cannot construct abstract class')
        } else {
            // ctx.body = { success: true }
            ctx.login(user.cn)
            ctx.redirect('/app')

        }
    })(ctx, next)
}))

app.use(route.get('/logout', function(ctx) {
    ctx.logout()
    ctx.redirect('/')
}))

// Require authentication for now
app.use(function(ctx, next) {
    if (ctx.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    } else {
        ctx.redirect('/')
    }
})

app.use(route.get('/app', function(ctx) {
    ctx.type = 'html'
    ctx.body = fs.createReadStream('views/app.html')
}))

// start server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server listening on', port))
```

error message

> ./../../koa-passport-example/server.js:53
>               throw new TypeError('error test')
>               ^
>   TypeError: error test

How do I need to modify the middleware,to fix it?
Have better way to complete this certification?

Comment: can you share server.js too?

Comment: i am already update the server.js please see that